# Nature of Current in AC Circuit under the presence of Capacitors

Tags: electric-current, classical-electrodynamics

In AC circuits under the presence of a capacitor and an AC power source the current leads by a phasor factor of $π/2$ with respect to the potential difference across the capacitor at any point of time as shown.[image]
My doubt here lies in the fact when time $t=0$, which is just the time when we connect the power source with the circuit, the current in circuit has a finite positive value even though potential difference is zero.

Doesn't this defy the laws of conservation of energy through Kirchoff's Loop Law?

Please explain where my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can interpret that result as the capacitor releasing charge at that certain time. These equations are the stationary ones, i.e. the system has a different transitory response when you switch it on. This phase difference in the current means that the capacitor has been charged at some point in the past (at $t = -\frac{\pi}{2\omega}$).

Comment: I don't understand the final sentence.  If the capacitor is initially uncharged, the current is zero for $t < 0$ and equal to the function given for $t > 0$ so I don't see any requirement that the capacitor has been charged in the past (before connecting the source).

Comment: It only means that $t=0$ does not correspont to the instant at which the AC source is switched, it's just an arbitrary instant where the system is in the stationary mode.

Answer (score 0):

To analyse this circuit to the detail required by your question requires one to make some assumptions.
One way is to say that there is resistance and (parasitic) inductance in the circuit and in fact what you have is equivalent to an LCR series circuit driven by the alternating voltage source.
For such a circuit there is an initial transient phase during which one has to take account of the fact that the circuit has a natural frequency $\omega_0^2 = \frac {1}{LC}$. During this phase the oscillations are damped because of the presence of resistance in the circuit.
After a time the transients die away and you have the steady state behavior which in your example is the current in the circuit leading the voltage across the capacitor by $\frac \pi 2$.

Rather then go through the analysis which is detained on many internet sites and textbooks I have used a [circuit simulator](http://spinningnumbers.org/circuit-sandbox/index.html) which I must warn you did not work for me using my normal browser, Firefox,  but did work with Edge.

To illustrate what happens I set up the following circuit with the component values chosen such that the frequency of voltage supply was well below the resonant frequency of the circuit.

[image]

Using the **TRAN**sient button I then looked at the response over a number of time scales - 20 ms, 100 ms, 500 ms and 5 seconds.

[image]

The resulting graphs illustrate the decay of the transients and the final steady state response of the circuit with the voltage across the capacitor and current very close to being $\frac \pi 2 $ out of phase.
Using the simulator or doing the mathematical analysis you can investigate the effect of making both $L$ and $R$ smaller and smaller.
So there is no violation of Kirchhoff's laws when analysing your circuit.

If you are not interested in the transient behaviour another way of analysing the circuit is, at the start via a delta function, giving the capacitor just the right amount of charge so that the equations in your question are both satisfied.

Comment: This circuit can easily be analyzed in the ideal circuit context (without the need for adding any parasitic inductance and resistance) to see that KVL is not violated.  Not there's anything wrong with your approach above but is it necessary?  Also, why would there need to be an initial charge on the capacitor?  The voltage source has zero volts across at $t=0$ so connecting an *charged* capacitor at $t=0$ would be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

First, if the "power source" (voltage source actually) is connected at $t = 0$, then your schematic should have a series connected *switch* that closes at $t = 0$ to indicate this fact.

Second, a switched circuit with an AC source can't be analyzed using AC circuit analysis since AC analysis assumes AC steady state (no transients).  Indeed the voltage and current functions you show in the picture do not hold in the case of a switched circuit.

Now, since the (assume uncharged) capacitor is connected at $t = 0$, the voltage across the capacitor is given by (assuming ideal circuit theory context)

$$v_C(t) = u(t) \cdot V_o\sin\omega t$$

where $u(t)$ is the [unit step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).  The current through the capacitor is then

$$i_C(t) = C\frac{dv_C}{dt} = C\left[\delta (t)  \cdot V_o\,\sin\omega t + u(t) \cdot \omega V_o\,\cos\omega t\right] = u(t) \cdot \omega C\, V_o\,\cos\omega t$$

Note that for this special case where the voltage across the voltage source happens to be zero at the instant the capacitor is connected, the voltage across the capacitor is *continuous* but, since the *derivative* of the voltage across is discontinuous, the current through is discontinuous, i.e., the current 'jumps' from *zero* just before the switch closes to $\omega C\, V_0$ just after the switch closes.

> Doesn't this defy the laws of conservation of energy through
>   Kirchoff's Loop Law?

No, the power delivered / absorbed by the voltage source equals the power absorbed / delivered by the capacitor at all times.

$$p_S = v_S\cdot i_C = u(t) \cdot \frac{\omega C\, V^2_o}{2}\sin2\omega t$$

$$p_C = v_C\cdot i_C = u(t) \cdot \frac{\omega C\, V^2_o}{2}\sin2\omega t$$

Using the online circuit simulator [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/), I quickly simulated this circuit, using transient analysis from $t = 0$ to $t = 10\,\mathrm{ms}$, to verify the above results:

[image]

[image]